# rotating image in javascript problems

Tags: php, html

i have some beginer problem
i am doing this website http://www.rotujeme.eu  it s all about rotating image and when you click on zrotuj si sam, popup window should take your jpg and use it on next page, which is opened only if you have enabled popup in browser

here is my issue, many people dont have this function, because of ads and stuff

my question is, how to do this thing?

i thought about redirect small popup and maximize it, but javascript didnt work

my second question is about using user's file

in code i have done it this way
you upload your img to server and script rename it to for example img.jpg and index.php use this name of picture and rotate it on rotujeme.eu/upload(this is site, which is opened by zrotuj si sam)
but that is not ideal, beacuse browsers have cache and use old code and files, so if you upload new file, youll see only old one

and of course, second thing is, that anybody can see, what you had rotated 
i want to connect somehow page, where you upload and page where you see it rotated and make possible more users do this
can somebody help with this? thank you

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. Can you clarify, or at least post some code?

Answer (score 0):

ok ill try

first question

this is upload button on the index.php page

```
<a href="/rotkanye/"  onclick="window.open('rotuj.php', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250'); return false;">  <div class="upload-button">

<div class="upload-cover">ZROTUJ SI SÁM!
    </div>

</div> <!-- .upload-button --> </a>
```

this button open rotuj.php, which cotains

```
<?php Header("Cache-Control: max-age=1, must-revalidate");  if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
      if($file_size > 5097152){
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 5 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true){
         if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"upload/upload/"."juju.png")){
sleep(1);

echo "<script>
window.open('upload/');</script>";

echo "<script>
window.close();</script>";
sleep(1);
}
         echo "Prave roto ide!";
      }
else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
 }

?>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Povedz roticom</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styl1.css" type="text/css">

<style>

h1 {color: white;
left:0;
right:0;

}

</style>

</head>
   <body>
      <h1>Pridaj rotografiu:</h1>

      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="image" />
         <input type="submit"/>
      </form>
         </body>
</html>
```

i d like to know, how to get to the rotujeme.eu/upload/index.php after code is done

---

and second question was about uploading file, when you select your image, script will upload it, name it juju.jpg and index.php in rotujeme.eu/upload/ will use it
i want to do it in way, that when you use your own file, only you can see it on next window and then it will be deleted or renamed

```
<div id="primaryContainer"> <a class="btn_join_small" href="#" style="float: center;">
            <img class="loading_arrow" src="upload/juju.png" />
        </a>
```

this is part of code, which is using uploaded image in rotujeme.eu/upload/index.php